# I want to use spawn from node js with python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I need to use a python3 script executed by js sever, i dont know how to set the variables like --name on spawn, thats my problem.

this is my code on js:

```
var { spawn } = require('child_process');

console.log("--------------------SART---------------------");
       
var path = "/home/usr/Documentos/Proyectos/Repos/test_recurrent.py";


pythonProcess = spawn('python3',[path]);


console.log("--------------------SPAWN---------------------");
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });
  
  pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });
  
  pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
```

I need execute this line :

```
python3 test_recurrent.py --name "Default_name" --dataroot "/home/usr/UIInputs" --which_epoch 72000 --ancho_ventana 512 --alto_ventana 1200 --numero_imagenes 4 --numero_generaciones 7 --output_path "/home/usr/UIResults" --xcoor 1526 1526 1526 1526 --ycoor 3995 3995 3995 3995
```

i have no idea about how to set this variables.

Comment: What's wrong with the given code?

Comment: You already passing your `path` variable as an argument to the python call. Just do the same for the rest of the arguments. The 2nd argument to `spawn` is an array that can contain all the arguments.

Comment: I have tried but I do not know how to do it, if you could give me an example with one value of the problem I would appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass switches as list after your path

```
var { spawn } = require('child_process');

console.log("--------------------SART---------------------");
       
var scriptPath = "/home/usr/Documentos/Proyectos/Repos/test_recurrent.py";

pythonProcess = spawn('python3', [scriptPath, "--name", "Default_name", "--dataroot", "/home/usr/UIInputs", "--which_epoch", "72000", "--ancho_ventana", "512", "--alto_ventana", "1200", "--numero_imagenes", "4", "--numero_generaciones", "7", "--output_path", "/home/usr/UIResults", "--xcoor", "1526 1526 1526 1526", "--ycoor", "3995 3995 3995 3995"]);

console.log("--------------------SPAWN---------------------");
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });
  
  pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });
  
  pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
```

Comment: Thats the solution